# Rangy causing Chrome Extension to be rejected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, rangy

I'm using rangy-core.js as a part of my Chrome extension, but as soon as the extension is uploaded it gets rejected due to malware policy. In order to narrow down the problem, I removed the rangy js files and uploaded the exact same extension. This time around there was no malware policy problem, and the extension was allowed to be published. What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: This may shed some light https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/69

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks for the link. I tried it out, but this didn't solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Were you using a minified/obfuscated version of the lib?